# Python - How do I install Pmw in ubuntu?

Tags: python

In my pydev eclipse appears unresolved imports: Pmw, I've downloaded the Pmw from: http://pmw.sourceforge.net/ http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmw/files/ ,to be specific the Pmw2 one, it comes with a folder called Pwd2, what is supposed that I'm going to do with the folder? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Untar the file: `tar xvzf foo.tar.gz`
2. cd foo
3. sudo python setup.py install